# How can I use raw SQL in NestJS instead of TypeOrm or Sequelize?

Tags: sql, orm, sequelize.js, nestjs, typeorm

As of today TypeOrm has 1.493 issues over 282.102 weekly downloads and Sequelize 783 issues over 571.781 weekly downloads in Github.

As I read over the TypeOrm and Sequelize Github issues, I want to avoid those major problemas by coding raw SQL instead of dealing with major issues like losing data, columns being dropped when you synchronize entities or types being changed due to default ORM types.

I use NestJs 7.0.3 with TypeGraphQL, PostgreSQL v12.2 and TypeScript.
Since 2019, I've had two issues raised with TypeOrm.

I understand the advantages of using an ORM but I wonder if NestJS can work efficiently if I use raw SQL in order to replace TypeORM or Sequelize entirely?

Thanks so much for your insights.
Ron

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always create your own [Dynamic Module](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules), using a database driver of your choice. I have a database module based off the [node-pg](https://node-postgres.com/) package and have loved writing my own SQL for it. [You can view the source code here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/tree/master/apps/api/src/app/database). It's not a published package, but it should help you get to where you want.

Comment: I cheched your github repo and the zeldaPlay source code is amazing.   You created your own Dynamic Module.  After all you have done with the node-pg package, would you replace in your developments an ORM in order to avoid those issues I mentioned above or would you rather deal with the trade off and use Typeorm/Sequelize ?

Comment: There's a lot of refactoring going on behind the scenes. Gonna be removing the transient scope and instead working with all singletons, just by creating new provider tokens instead of using the same class name (similar to how the TypeOrm package for Nest works). It should make testing easier, but it'll be a while before I get to that

Comment: I usually avoid ORMs as I don't feel they bring as many advantages as they do negatives in the end of things. Plus, this way, I **know** what is being executed on my SQL server.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing your experience. As a summary,  in order to go this "raw-sql" route I should start (1) reading the manual for node-pg  (2) reading nestjs Dynamic Module (3) creating my own Dynamic Module   (4) Compare my code with your working code.    Would you suggest any additional readings before I enter this unplanned journey?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use my code as a comparison, I do use a few helper packages to make things easier; however, [this article](https://dev.to/nestjs/build-a-nestjs-module-for-knex-js-or-other-resource-based-libraries-in-5-minutes-12an) is really well written and starts getting into some of the working of Dynamic Modules. John has a lot of good Nest articles so find some stuff that interests you from him if you want as well. [Here's another of his](https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370)

Comment: All these related pieces were the direction I was looking for: Thank you for sharing so much information  Best regards.